# How to implement OPA with Django microservices?

Tags: django, authentication, authorization, open-policy-agent

I am starting a project where there'll be a bunch of microservices in Django. I want to implement a separate Authentication and Authorization system that all the microservices will talk to for end-user auth.

So, my doubts are:

1. What approach should I take?
2. I have looked at OPA and it seems promising but I can't seem to figure out the implementation.
3. I also looked at some other authorization systems like [Google's Zanzibar](https://research.google/pubs/pub48190/). Is it any good?

Comment: I don't think you've given enough information to give you a good answer. What authorization use cases do you have?

Comment: Open Policy Agent and Zanzibar are general frameworks that are use-case agnostic. It's a great pattern to centralize permissions across microservices. Also interested in this as a way to centralize authorization in Django instead of defining it on every API endpoint.